# Using a field separator of the two-character string "\n" in awk

Tags: awk, gawk

My input file has a plain-text representation of the newline character in it separating the fields:

```
First line\nSecond line\nThird line
```

I would expect the following to replace that text `\n` with a newline:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\n"; OFS = "\n" } { print $1 }' test.txt                                                                                                                                  
First line\nSecond line\nThird line
```

But it doesn't (gawk 4.0.1 / OpenBSD nawk 20110810).

I'm allowed to separate on just the `\`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\"; OFS = "\n" } { print $1, $2 }' test.txt 
First line
nSecond line
```

I can also use a character class in gawk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "[[:punct:]]n"; OFS = "\n" } { $1 = $1; print $0 }' test.txt 
First line
Second line
Third line
```

But I feel like I should be able to specify the exact separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A field separator is a type of regexp and when using a dynamic regexp you need to double escape everything:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS = "\\\\n"; OFS = "\n" } { print $1 }' file
First line
```

See the man page for details.

Answer (score 2):

Here `sed` might be a better tool for this task

```
sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

Comment: re better tool: for the minimum example in my post, yes. For the original program I needed, awk needed to be used, it just had a strange record separator.

Comment: You can always divide and conquer.  `... | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' | awk '...`